# How to access the first two digits of a number

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs

I want to access the first two digits of a number, and i have tried using substring, substr and slice but none of them work. It's throwing an error saying substring is not defined.

```
render() {

        let trial123 = this.props.buildInfo["abc.version"];

        var str = trial123.toString();

        var strFirstThree = str.substring(0,3);

        console.log(strFirstThree);
}
```

I have tried the above code

output of(above code) 
trial123=19.0.0.1

I need only 19.0

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would split it by dot and then take the first two elements:

```js
const trial = "19.0.0.1"

console.log(trial.split(".").slice(0, 2).join("."))
// 19.0
```

Comment: whatever the approach u r saying is absolutely right i don't comment on this 

but split/slice/substring/ whatever i use 

its throws error like its "UNDEFINED"

so do i need to define?

Answer (score 0):

You could just `split` and then `join`:

```
const [ first, second ] = trial123.split('.');
const result = [ first, second ].join('.');
```

Comment: After trying your code  
                                                                                      
I got error like 

Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

Comment: then your `trial123` doesn't exist as the string "19.0.0.1"

Comment: your point is correct

here my input look like 

array{
build.number="12.3.4",build.version="19.0.0.1"

}

i'm accessing build version first and then trying to split after

 accessing build version alone it will become

19.0.0.1

how can i split now?

help me out please

Comment: Once you have build version in its own variable, just use that variable name in place of `trial123`, should work fine.

Comment: First converting the integer into string and then accessing first two digit works ..       


let digit = '' + num;


        const [ first, second ] = digit.split('.');


        const result = [ first, second ].join('.');



thank u @Davin Tryon

Answer (score 0):

I have added a code snippet of the work: (explanation comes after it, line by line).

```js
function getFakePropValue(){
   return Math.round(Math.random()) == 0 ? "19.0.0.1" : null;
}

let trial123 = getFakePropValue() || "";
//var str = trial123.toString();  
// is the toString() really necessary? aren't you passing it along as a String already?
var strFirstThree = trial123.split('.');
//var strFirstThree = str.substring(0,3);
//I wouldn't use substring , what if the address 191.0.0.1 ?
if(strFirstThree.length >= 2)
    console.log(strFirstThree.splice(0,2).join("."));
else 
    console.error("prop was empty");
```

Because you are using **React**, the `props` value was faked with the function `getFakePropValue`. The code inside is irrelevant, what I am doing is returning a `String` randomly, in case you have allowed in your React Component for the prop to be empty. This is to show how you an create minimal robust code to avoid having exceptions.

Moving on, the following is a safety net to make sure the variable `trial123` always has a string value, even if it's `""`.

```
let trial123 = getFakePropValue() || "";
```

That means that if the function returns something like `null` , the boolean expression will execute the second apart, and return an empty string `""` and that will be the value for `trial123`.

Moving on, the line where you convert to `toString` I have removed, I assume you are already getting the value in string format. Next.

```
var strFirstThree = trial123.split('.');
```

That creates an array where each position holds a part of the IP addrss. So 19.0.0.1 would become `[19,0,0,1]` that's thanks to the split by the delimiter `.` . Next.

```
if(strFirstThree.length >= 2)
    console.log(strFirstThree.splice(0,2).join("."));
else 
    console.error("prop was empty");
```

This last piece of code uses the conditional if to make sure that my array has values before I try to `splice` it and `join`. The conditional is not to avoid an exception, since `splice` and `join` on empty arrays just returns an empty string. It's rather for you to be able to raise an error or something if needed. So if the array has values, I keep the first two positions with `splice(0,2)` and then join that array with a '.'. I recommend it more than the `substr` method you were going for because what if you get a number that's **191.0.0.1** then the `substr` would return the wrong string back, but with `splice` and `join` that would never happen.

**Things to improve**

- I would strongly suggest using more human comprehensible variables (reflect their use in the code)
- The right path for prop value checking is through [Prop.Types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), super easy to use, very helpful.

Happy coding!